# PHP SDK / Facebook graph API Location based events

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How do you get events based on your current location?
I already try via FQL, but in the query the 'where' clausule had to be an indexable column, but I need to search all events in a radius of e.g. 5 miles.

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like this:

```
$lat = "47.960";
$long = "12.091";

// using offset gives us a "square" on the map from where to search the events
$offset = 0.4;

$events = 'SELECT pic_big, name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND venue.longitude  \''. ($long-$offset) .'\' AND venue.latitude > \''. ($lat-$offset) .'\'. $limit;
```

but for that you will need to get lattitude and longitude of the location you are searching in.

Hope that helps in some way

Comment: Thanks, but is this based on all events from your region or just the events you're attending?